# Combine values in all rows when column header is the same

Tags: vba, excel

Another tricky problem. I have a cleaned data set with another macro, where I need to loop over the column headers and for each row, combine the values of the columns with the same header name in the first column, separated by `;`

Sample data:

```
Test    Country     Test    Country 
123      456         789      012
abc      def         ghi      jkl
mno      pqr         stu      vwx
```

Desired output:

```
Test      Country
123;789   456;012
abc;ghi   def;jkl
```

I have tried something like this which definitely didn't work:

```
    Dim i As Long
i = 1
j = 1
Do Until Len(Cells(i, j).Value) = 0
    If Cells(i, j).Value = Cells(i, j + 1).Value Then
        Cells(i, j).Value = Cells(i, j).Value & ";" & Cells(i, j + 1).Value

        Rows(j + 1).Delete
    Else
        i = i + 1
        j = j + 1
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: Do you know your columns with like headers? Try using `.Offset()` if you know your column ranges. (Like if you know A1 is Test, and C1 is Test, you could loop everything in A and concatenate it with C)

Comment: Thanks, I won't know the column ranges, they are not hardcoded, so I need to loop through and match on the name always

Comment: This could be a lot of fun! Have you tried looping through columns+rows with two for loops? Like `For Each column In colRange` // `For Each row In rowRange` and then do a comparison/concatenate?

Comment: If you have Office 365 Excel you can use TextJoin().

Comment: Don't have Office 365, unfortunately

Comment: @ScottHoltzman His columns change, he has no way of telling where like-titled columns will be.

Comment: No, needs to be done in vba and the remaining columns should be deleted while doing this. Also what @Tyeler said

Comment: @MJ95 Will the first header always start in A1?

Comment: @Tyeler yes, headers go from A1 to usually XC-XQ somewhere there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a nice chat as agreed ...

```
Sub ForLoopPair()

Dim lastRow As Integer: lastRow = Cells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row     ' or w/e you had
Dim lastCol As Integer: lastCol = Cells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column  ' or w/e you had

For DestCol = 1 To lastCol
   For ReadCol = DestCol + 1 To lastCol
      If Cells(1, DestCol) = Cells(1, ReadCol) Then
         For i = 2 To lastRow
            If Cells(i, ReadCol) <> "" Then
               Cells(i, DestCol) = Cells(i, DestCol) & ";" & Cells(i, ReadCol)
            End If
         Next i
      End If
   Next ReadCol
Next DestCol

For DestCol = 1 To lastCol
   If Cells(1, DestCol) = "" Then Exit For
   For ReadCol = lastCol To (DestCol + 1) Step -1
      If Cells(1, DestCol) = Cells(1, ReadCol) Then
         Columns(ReadCol).Delete
      End If
   Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: there are some faults: 1) `xlCellTypeLastCell` is not the proper way to get the last used cell in a row or column. in SO there are posts about how to properly get the _last one_ 2) in the first loop you're iterating over the same cells uselessly not checking for the current "header" to have already been processed 3) `Cells(1, DestCol)` inside `For ReadCol` loop should be substituted with a variable and avoid multiple accesses to the same cell that doesn't change during that loop. 2) and 3) heavily affects the performance of the macro because accessing cells is a very time consuming activity

Comment: @user3598756 1) The user is using the xlUp method you refer to on other posts. For a clean worksheet the two functions are the same. 2) The very first thing stated is 'after a nice chat as agreed' why don't you see I was walking the op through a solution? 3) I already explained to the user in the chat the time consumption and the need to increase the performance of this code. 4) When learning something it is better to understand what to do then optimize. 5) Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: I was (and I am) not reading all the chat since there was (and still is) an _accepted_ solution which all my comments were (and still are) addressed to.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's different about the first answer but this one is tested in Excel 2010 with sample data provided

Sub B()

```
  Dim DestCol As Integer
  Dim ReadCol As Integer

  DestCol = 1
  ReadCol = 2

  While ActiveSheet.Cells(1, DestCol) <> ""
     If ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ReadCol) = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, DestCol) Then
        For i = 2 To ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
           If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ReadCol) <> "" Then
              ActiveSheet.Cells(i, DestCol) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, DestCol) & ";" & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ReadCol)
           End If
        Next i
        ActiveSheet.Columns(ReadCol).Delete
     ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ReadCol + 1) <> "" Then
        ReadCol = ReadCol + 1
     Else
        ReadCol = DestCol + 2
        DestCol = DestCol + 1
     End If
  Wend
```

End Sub

Comment: I see the difference here, I delete ReadCol instead of in previous answer where I delete DestCol. 
    ReadCol = DestCol + 2 is correct because you always Read from one column to the right of the destination until the last column

Comment: Sorry, does not work. It only works once for the first instance. For example, If i put a few more columns in between it doesn't work

Comment: Okay, well I give up. Do you have a link to your current data?

Comment: Above is basically my current data EDIT: The structure is identical, except for sometimes there are a variable number of columns in between

Comment: Using this answer I started with  
Test | Country | Test | Blah | Country | Foo | Bar | Test
123 | 456 | 789 | xxx | 012 | xxx | xxx | 345 | 
abc | def | ghi | xxx | jkl | xxxx | xxx | mno
mno | pqr | stu | xxx | vwx | xxx | xxx | vwx

And got the result  
Test | Country | Blah | Foo | Bar
123;789;345 | 456;12 | xxx | xxx | xxx
abc;ghi;mno | def;jkl | xxx | xxxx | xxx
mno;stu;vwx | pqr;vwx | xxx | xxx | xxx

Comment: I will try again, but I don't see how you got that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125373/discussion-between-j-reid-and-mj95).

Answer (score 0):

Try this (tested)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, cell2 As Range, cell3 As Range, rngToDelete As Range
    Dim txt As String

    With Worksheets("myWorksheetName")
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
            Set rngToDelete = .Offset(1).Resize(, 1)
            For Each cell In .Cells
                If Intersect(cell, rngToDelete) Is Nothing Then
                    Set rng = GetRange(cell, .Cells)
                    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                        With Intersect(.Parent.UsedRange, cell.EntireColumn)
                        MsgBox .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants).Address                            
                            For Each cell2 In .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants)
                                txt = cell2.Value
                                For Each cell3 In rng
                                    txt = txt & ";" & .Parent.Cells(cell2.row, cell3.Column)
                                Next cell3
                                cell2.Value = txt
                            Next cell2
                        End With
                        Set rngToDelete = Union(rng, rngToDelete)
                    End If
                End If
            Next cell
            Intersect(.Cells, rngToDelete).EntireColumn.Delete
         End With
    End With
End Sub


Function GetRange(rngToSearchFor As Range, rngToSearchIn As Range) As Range
    Dim f As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String

    With rngToSearchIn
        Set f = .Find(What:=rngToSearchFor.Value, lookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, After:=rngToSearchFor, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
           If f.Column > rngToSearchFor.Column Then
                firstAddress = f.Address
                Set GetRange = f
                Do
                   Set GetRange = Union(GetRange, f)
                   Set f = .FindNext(f)
                Loop While f.Column > rngToSearchFor.Column
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: No, this didn't combine anything and just cut off the last part of the strings in the column headers

Comment: I'm not by PC so just wrote down an idea. It's a success it compiled! I'll be able to test it in some 10 hours. In the meanwhile you can step through it (with F8) and try to see where it fails

Comment: MJ95, try this code and see my comments in @JReid answer. And let me know